# nginx domain rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a following config for domains:

```
server {
    listen                  80;
    server_name             www.xxxx.ru yyyy.ru www.yyyy.ru;
    rewrite                 ^ http://xxxx.ru$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen                  80;
    server_name             xxxx.ru;
}
```

I need to redirect all these domains to the main domain:

```
http://www.xxxx.ru/some/path => http://xxxx.ru/some/path
http://yyyy.ru/some/path => http://xxxx.ru/some/path
http://www.yyyy.ru/some/path => http://xxxx.ru/some/path
```

But with this config I have:

```
http://www.xxxx.ru/some/path => http://xxxx.ru/some/path (good)
http://yyyy.ru/some/path => http://xxxx.ru//some/path (double slash)
http://www.yyyy.ru/some/path => http://xxxx.ru (no path)
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that I had to clear browser history, because previous experiments were bad and the redirects are permanent. Config works very well, but my head is not :(